# In Neo4j, is there anyway to create a graph projection if your graph is too big to fit in memory? The estimate is 152GB for my very large graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with 18 billion relationships and roughly 2 million nodes.   I need to perform an embedding using FASTRP and the memory estimate for the graph projection is 152 GB.   Is there anyway around creating the graph projection?  I only have 64GB of RAM on my desktop.

Comment: 18 billion relationships is a lot. You could try it out and see if the estimates are wrong by overwriting protection using sudo:true in configuration. Other than that, there is not much you can do except get a bigger machine

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a definitive answer, since it would depend on your needs with this processed data.

You may try to create clusters, using the write method (writes the cluster id directly as a property in memory), or any kind of community like that before, and run an algorithm for each of these clusters.

This way you could iterate through each community in order to create other graphs (that would probably fit your RAM size) and work with your whole data. The downside of this is that your results won't be 100% equal if you could project the whole graph in memory in order to apply the algorithms, but in this case (not enough RAM) I believe it's a good trade.